# Is it possible to plot more than two scalars in the same plot in tensorboard?

Tags: tensorflow, tensorboard

Is it possible to plot more than two scalars in the same plot? More specifically. it could allow:

- training loss and test loss being plotted together
- regularization loss and top level loss to be plotted together.
- maybe adding accuracy on the right vertical axis

Just name a few. This would help a lot.

Answer (score 0):

The [github documentation for TensorBoard](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/tensorflow/tensorboard/README.md) says that it only overlaps plots from different runs with the same tag name, so this won't work. If you'd like this feature please file a bug.